# How to shirk print / puts in Ruby oneliners?

Tags: ruby

Consider oneliner

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 1 + 1'
```

which uses `ruby` as a command-line calculator. I would like to write the expression without `puts`. Is there a switch for it in `ruby` command?

Comment: How are you going to use this?

Comment: Like this: `$ ruby -e 'require "sy"; puts 42.kWh.in :MJ'`
And while I can't avoid requiring `sy` gem, I'd like to avoid writing `puts`...

Comment: I encourage more answer to this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible with ruby command line switches, but it’s easily achievable with shell:

```
⮀ cat /usr/local/bin/rubyoneliner
#!/bin/sh
ruby -e "puts $@"

⮀ rubyoneliner '1 + 1'
2
```

or with bash/zsh function.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, so `/usr/local/bin` is the right place to put this sorts of scripts in?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to pass further command options to my `rubyoneliner` script?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is fine, yes. Personal scripts are usually stored in `~/bin`, but the latter is not included to the `$PATH` by default on all distros. The second question: if there are other options to be specifically treated, you probably should slice the last parameter in `rubyoneliner` and construct the call to `ruby` more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have an implicit print in ruby. However, you can shrink your oneliner a little more -> replacing puts by p and including the require in the shell command :

```
$ ruby -rsy -e 'p 42.kWh.in :MJ'
```

`-rsy` whould replace the `require 'sy'`.

Otherwise you can use the fact that the option `-p`, implicitely puts the `$_` variable with something like (much longer however) :

```
$ printf whatever | ruby -rsy -pe '$_ = 42.kWh.in :MJ'
```

or uglier

```
$ printf whatever | ruby -rsy -pe 'sub("whatever", 42.kWh.in :MJ)'
```